# JsFiddle URL with trailing slash being evaluated as correct link

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a small method that evaluates JSFiddle snippet URLs.

A valid JSFiddle snippet URL looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/y200sqpr/ or https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/y200sqpr.

An invalid URL is anything else.

It seems to work well, but for some strange reason it evaluates https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/ to true. How can I fix this.

```js
// this should evaluate to false
console.log(checkCourseContentElementCodeFiddleUrl("https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/"));

// this should evaluate to true
console.log(checkCourseContentElementCodeFiddleUrl("https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/y200sqpr/"));

function checkCourseContentElementCodeFiddleUrl(url) {
    return !!url.match(/((\/\/\/?|https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?jsfiddle\.net\/.+\/.?([?#].*)?)/gi);
  }
```

Comment: Why is `https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/` "invalid"? That would just be an "anonymous" snippet

Comment: Why shouldn't that be true? The regexp only requires one more `/` after `jsfiddle.net/`

Comment: @Andreas a valid snippet has three parts in the URL, https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/y200sqpr/. If you browse to https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego, it takes you to a 404 error page.

Comment: That's true for your user, but this doesn't stop anonymous fiddles: https://jsfiddle.net/nb1kj30f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is if the last character is `/` then remove it before the regex check, so it will pass only if there's a second parameter in the URL.

**Working example**

```js
// this should evaluate to false
console.log(checkCourseContentElementCodeFiddleUrl("https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/"));

// this should evaluate to true
console.log(checkCourseContentElementCodeFiddleUrl("https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/y200sqpr/"));

function checkCourseContentElementCodeFiddleUrl(url) {
  if (url.endsWith("/")) url = url.substring(0, url.length - 1)
  return !!url.match(/((\/\/\/?|https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?jsfiddle\.net\/.+\/.?([?#].*)?)/gi);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem just is in the expression.

```
console.log(checkCourseContentElementCodeFiddleUrl("https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/"));
console.log(checkCourseContentElementCodeFiddleUrl("https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/y200sqpr/"));
                        
function checkCourseContentElementCodeFiddleUrl(url) {
    return url.match(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?jsfiddle\.net\/[\w\d]+\/[\w\d]+\/?$/g);
}
```